# How can I disable the info pop up in Blender?

Tags: interface, customization

How do I disable the pop up in Blender that gives you a description and or the source of an aspect of Blender?

Answer (score 3):

**Preferences** > **Interface**

You'll see a checkbox in the Display section labeled "**Tooltips**". Uncheck it.

[image: Blender Preferences - Tooltips disabled]

By the way, even with Tooltips disabled, you can still view them on an as-needed basis by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> before hovering over an interface item.